# Dynamic listView Add x columns and x rows

Tags: c#, listview, subitem

This is my code:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM stock";
cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, mdb);
SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    var_depot = reader["depot"].ToString();

    ajouterlistview1 = new ListViewItem(reader["id"].ToString());
    ajouterlistview1.SubItems.Add(reader["article"].ToString());

    listView1.Items.Add(ajouterlistview1);
    listView1.Refresh();

    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (var_depot == listView1.Columns[i].Text)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < listView1.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                /*if (listView1.Columns[i].Text == var_depot )
                {*/
                listView1.Items[j].SubItems[1].Text = reader["quantite"].ToString();
                //}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code work fine but when I change this line:

```
listView1.Items[j].SubItems[1].Text = reader["quantite"].ToString();
```

to this line :

```
listView1.Items[j].SubItems[i].Text = reader["quantite"].ToString();
```

I get a error because my row X is not defined :/

What should I do please?

Comment: What is "row X"? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: I get this error InvalidArgument=value '5' is not indexed

Comment: You mean "Invalid argument value of '5' is not valid for 'index'"?

Comment: look this picture:
http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/368148tableau.jpg

X row is the dynamique lines
i have a dynamique head with X colomn
so i have X Row too but its not define so i get a error :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have more `listView1.Columns` than `listView1.Items[...].SubItems`. Add some empty subItems (`ajouterlistview1.SubItems.Add("")`) to make sure that you can have the access to listView1.Items[...].SubItems[i].Text.

Try this way:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (var_depot == listView1.Columns[i].Text)
        {
            ajouterlistview1.SubItems.Add(reader["quantite"].ToString());
            break;
        }
        else
            ajouterlistview1.SubItems.Add("");
    }
```

Comment: that is i have more listView1.Columns but i can't add ajouterlistview1.SubItems.Add("")
because i dont know what nombre of ajouterlistview1.SubItems.Add("") i have in my database, that can be 2 or 3 or 4 ...

Comment: I have updated my answer. I removed the block: for (int j = 0; j < listView1.Items.Count; j++) as I can see no reason for it.